# Is it possible to retrieve data from Kusto older than retention period?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to retrieve older data from the Kusto table after the retention period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you are referring to softDeletePolicy which is the time the data is keep available for query. If the time of softDeletePolicy passed the data would not be available for query, but if you have Data recoverability enabled, the data will be recoverable for 14 days after it's been soft deleted.

You can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy#the-policy-object

Comment: One comment: "recoverable" does not mean "querieable".
You will need to do this in two steps: 1) recover, 2) query.

Comment: If you are interested in partitioning your data (within the retention period) to hot and cold (hot being ready for fast query and cold residing in blob storage), please read on cache policy - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/cachepolicy

Comment: @VladikBranevich: How to recover data for querying? Is recover means Alter data retention period to a larger period?

Comment: Please read about Retention Policy - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy - recoverability is mentioned there.

Comment: @VladikBranevich: i agree recoverability is mentioned there but is "how to recover" mentioned there?

Comment: Recover procedure requires a support ticket and enabled recoverability

Comment: Here's an example of what can be achieved in a self-serve manner: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/undo-drop-table-command

Comment: @VladikBranevich I wish you make this feature self-serve

Comment: Please use http://aka.ms/kustouservoice to log this request. Thanks much!